# ¿Cómo filtrar filas de DataFrame en función de los últimos caracteres o dígitos de los items de una columna?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```
d2=
   cod  consul
0  231  890201
1  345  890202
2  611  890203
3  592  890303
4  598  890203
5  211  NaN
6  355  890202
7  711  NaN
8  592  890703
9  598  890501
```

Requiero un filtro que me permita extraer las filas cuyos valores en la columna 'consul' terminan en '03'. Cabe aclarar que todos los datos son tipo cadena.

En mi ejemplo el filtro que debería obtener sería:

```
filtro=
   cod  consul
2  611  890203
3  592  890303
4  598  890203
8  592  890703
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu columna es de tipo entero, para este caso concreto, lo más simple es obtener el **resto de la división entera entre 100** (modulo 100), lo cual nos dará el valor de los dos últimos dígitos, lo cual podemos usar para crear una mascara booleana:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> data = {"cod":  (231, 345, 611, 592, 598, 211, 355, 711, 592, 598),
            "consul":(890201, 890202, 890203, 890303, 890203,
                      np.nan, 890202, np.nan, 890703, 890501),
           }

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=int)
>>> df
   cod  consul
0  231  890201
1  345  890202
2  611  890203
3  592  890303
4  598  890203
5  211     NaN
6  355  890202
7  711     NaN
8  592  890703
9  598  890501

>>> mask = df.consul % 100 == 3
>>> df2 = df[mask]
>>> df2
   cod  consul
2  611  890203
3  592  890303
4  598  890203
8  592  890703
```

Si tu columna contiene cadenas Python puedes usar [`pandas.Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=str)
>>> mask = df.consul.str.endswith("03")
>>> df2 = df[mask]
>>> df2
   cod  consul
2  611  890203
3  592  890303
4  598  890203
8  592  890703
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero realmente ese dato es un valor cadena

Comment: @Carolina entonces usa `mask = df.consul[-3:] == "003"`

Comment: @Carolina he editado la respuesta agregando al final la forma de hacerlo si tu columna son cadenas, aunque presumiblemente será más ineficiente que si fueran enteros.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias es lo que necesito..